# Save a .txt file correctly (Java)

Tags: java, file, text, save

I run the following piece of processing (Java) code inside a bigger loop. These lines save a string in a `.txt` file called `kinectDEM.tmp`, before doing that, the old file is renamed to `kinectDEM1.txt` and the new one (`kinectDEM.tmp`) is renamed to `kinectDEM0.txt`.

It works fine but sometimes it get stuck and the `kinectDEM1.txt` file disappears, blocking the loop.

How can I fix it?

```
if (millis() > precedente + savingtimestep) {
   txt[0] = "ncols         600\nnrows         480\nxllcorner     0\nyllcorner     0\ncellsize      1\nNODATA_value  10\n" +kinectDEM;
   saveStrings("kinectDEM0.tmp", txt);
   precedente = millis();
   //  delete the old .txt file, from kinectDEM1 to kinectDEMtrash
   File f = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM1.txt"));
   boolean success = f.delete();

   //  rename the old .txt file, from kinectDEM0 to kinectDEM1
   File oldName1 = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM0.txt"));
   File newName1 = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM1.txt"));
   oldName1.renameTo(newName1);

   //  rename kinectDEM0.tmp file to kinectDEM0.txt
   File oldName2 = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM0.tmp"));
   File newName2 = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM0.txt"));
   oldName2.renameTo(newName2);
 }
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Is Processing (Java), I corrected my question.

Comment: Are you suppressing any exceptions in ur code?

Comment: No I'm not suppressing exceptions

Comment: ...just because I don't know how to do that. What kind of exceptions should I check for?